# How to access html attributes of current node in jsTree?

Tags: jquery, jstree

When using jsTree and hotkeys plugin I want to access html attributes of current node.

My hotkyes code looks like and gives me **undefined** but the node got an ID

```
        "c" : function (obj) {
            alert($(obj).attr('id'));
            ,
```

How can I access the node's html attributes?

Comment: -1 Learn to use capital letters at the start of a sentence. English, kind sir, do you speak it?

Comment: can you show us more code? This snippet is almost essentially useless. What does your HTML look like? What does the rest of the JS look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the currently selected node by using `this._get_node();` in your hotkey function, where `node` is the jQuery object of the `<li>` in your tree. `this._get_node().attr("id")` will return the `id` of the selected node.

If you want the currently hovered node however (when the user has not pressed space to select the node while traversing the tree using hotkeys) you can use:

```
"c" : function(event) {
    var node = this._get_node(this.data.ui.hovered);
    if(node) {
       var id = node.attr("id");
    }
}
```

Basic example in jsFiddle (press `C` for selected node, `D` for hovered node): http://jsfiddle.net/mfgLF/14/

Comment: That looks good. Could you tell me how I can access the node's name using jQuery?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'name', accompanied by a HTML snippet?

Comment: In my example http://jsfiddle.net/sTmrv/9/ it would be 'Basics', 'Login', etc....

Comment: `node.find("a:first").text()` should work. It's not ideal however, the `&nbsp;` is getting included as well so you'd have to get rid of that somehow. I've been looking through the documentation of jsTree but haven't been able to find methods or anything to retrieve a node's text unfortunately.